# I need advice on which device to get to be able to run Wolfram notebook applications on the go on mobile phones?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, wolfram-player

I am planning to get a new phone later this month since I have moved to a new country and my old phone is causing me difficulties. I see there are good deals on Samsung (Android) and iPhones (IOS). My issue is I want to run notebook applications locally on my phone. So if I create a program that does something useful and I want to use it on the go then I want to run it locally on my mobile.

So my question is which device is more preferable for this usage. I see there are two types of applications on mobile devices being published by a company named Wolfram Group LLC, `Wolfram Cloud` and `Wolfram Player`. I am assuming the `Wolfram Cloud` app will not run the notebook application on the local mobile hardware so would be pretty slow and not feasible for computationally intensive applications.

So if anyone that has been using these apps on their devices, please share their experience on which phone to get. Also, I see that the `Wolfram Player` app is not available on the Google Play Store. Maybe there are some other Android stores where I can get the `Wolfram Player` app?

Finally, I am a long term windows user so I don't know much about how Samsung vs iPhone will behave in terms of connectivity with windows.

Also, please somebody explain if `Wolfram Player` can run notebook application directly then what is the purpose of CDF vs NB?

Comment: So far I know, no phone can run .nb file locally.

Comment: So far I know, CDF can't do symbolic evaluation, for exemple evaluate `a+a` to `2 a`

Comment: ... but I would be happy to be wrong.